# How to do django form backend validation for user inputs

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am NOT trying to use Django Form for rendering, but only for backend validation. This is my current code for a chat app:

views.py

```
def send(request):
    var1 = request.POST['var1']
    user_id= request.POST['user_id']

    main_user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)

    new_instance = ModelName.objects.create(var1=var1, user=main_user)
    new_instance.save()

    # Below is the alert message in ajax in template.
    return HttpResponse('Message sent successfully')
```

So, basically, I want to create a model chat instance in the database using the Django Form backend validation. However, I don't know how to do it. I hope you could help me with this.

Moreover, if there are any other security holes that I need to take care of in this form (other than backend validation), I would appreciate it if you could show me how to fix it. Thank you, and please leave any comments below.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i hope you are dong well

i think i can help you in this one as i worked with it recently

you should edit your view to look like this:

```
def send(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    user_id = request.POST.get('user_id')
    main_user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    
    form = ChatForm(request.POST, user=main_user)
    if form.is_valid():
        chat_instance = form.save(commit=False)  # Create instance without saving to DB
        # Perform any additional processing on chat_instance if needed
        chat_instance.save()  # Now save the instance to the DB
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})
    else:
        errors = form.errors.as_json()
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'errors': errors})
return HttpResponse('Not a valid request method')
```

and your forms to look like this:

```
class ChatForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.main_user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(ChatForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user'].initial = self.main_user #this the one you looking for

    class Meta:
        model = Chat
        fields = (
            'var1',
            'user',
        )
```

i hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks. But when I initilize the fields in the forms.py, it is not saved in the database... Is there something missing in the code?

Comment: yeah mb you should edit your save method to include commit=False
i will edit the answer

Comment: Yeah... but its still the same. I also wish to populate the variables in the form fields before the form.is_valid(), because I want to sanitize and validate the user inputs before saving it in the database. I don't see the point of adding the user inputs after I did the form.is_valid() method. Right?